# Listview with viewpager or other way?

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager, fragment

ViewPager with listview how to do this(look at the attachment)? I search many times without success

[click to see design picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83WHn.png)

please I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are trying to design a ListView with the top header can be scrolled horizontally. if it's the case, you can use StickyHeaderListView and make its header view a custom component composed of a HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: that's true, could you please give me and example code.

Comment: if that's true, please choose my solution as proper answer to your question~ @Ghamdan please read the source code from the following example: https://github.com/romainguy/road-trip